# MS Word - Bulk Content Control Duplication

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-interop, word-contentcontrol

I'm creating an [Application-Level Add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157892(v=vs.100).aspx#applevel) for MS Word 2007, 2010 & 2013 which needs to duplicate and modify a Content Control and it's contents 1 to 1000+ times.

Does anyone have any tips as to the best approach\methods to use when creating lots of duplicate Content Controls and modifying their contents?

So far I've hit a limit of around 800 duplicates before Word stops responding.  This was achieved using `Range.Copy` and `Range.PasteAndFormat` and refreshing the screen periodically every 50-100 records using `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenRefresh()`.  Content Controls are modified by registering to the `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ContentControlAfterAdd` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the content as Flat OPC XML, manipulate it via the Open XML SDK, and then inject it back into your docx again.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191178(v=office.14).aspx

For more on Flat OPC, see http://ericwhite.com/blog/flat-opc-expanded/

Comment: Thanks - Using Open Xml is definitely the way to go, although from my experience over the past few days it does require extra development effort.